# How do I make a record in ActiveRecord an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm really new to rails so I've been just tinkering around and trying to figure out stuff myself in a trial by fire, but I keep finding myself needing to look up new things

I'm trying to have 2 separate numbers, like an array, put into a single cell in an ActiveRecord table. I'm making a program that takes frame data from a character in a fighting game and puts it up against another character. So for each move I need the **startup** and the **endlag** of the move. I want to have something like under the column titled "Forward Aerial Attack" I want the table cell to read `(2, -14)` or something to that regard. But I also want a way I can use that in calculations like `"result = character.forwardair[0] + othercharacter.forwardair[1]"` or something in that type of regard.

Any help is appreciated. I just don't really know what to do tbh and I'm trying to figure out rails but coming from a python/java background rails has been completely new to me in terms of format.

EDIT: I'm using SQLite3 I think

Comment: Which database do you use? ActiveRecord supports PostgreSQL's arrays. There's also JSON support in some databases that might fit.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm using sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use separate table for that. It should store your character movement data just fine as columns. Add has_many relation pointed on that new table, ordered by id or creation_at (to preserve move order).
You will be able to use DB agregate funtions in such case if you need to show some stats.

Comment: Well each character has 2 values attached to each move. Like (4, -15) How would I do that in separate tables?